# Serial Port Programming?

Tags: c, windows, vb6, serial-port

I think This question might be very general...I am new to Serial port programming on windows(XP). I would appreciate for valuable suggestions on :- Where to start ? ( Any tutorial link ). Language C, VB6, I want to convert/send serial port data to USB data. to be more specific I have a firmware controlling USB device. I want to Rx/Tx data on serial port ( test equipment ) to USB firmware ( USB device)...

Thanks

Comment: Which language? It could be as simple as `set f [open COM1 w];puts $f "hello";flush $f` in Tcl to half a page of code in C.

Comment: Language C, VB6, I want to convert/send serial port data to USB data. to be more specific I have a firmware controlling USB device. I want to Rx/Tx data on serial port ( test equipment ) to USB firmware ( USB device)...

Comment: So did you search for _windows usb port c_ or _windows usb port vb_? What did you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does "convert/send serial port data to USB data" mean?  Do you want a RS-232 to USB converter (i.e. http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8580)?  If you want to learn about serial interfaces and how to communicate with them using Windows then I would recommend the book "Serial Port Complete" by Jan Axelson.